# JQuery isn't working but works on JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've honestly tried everything and I've been at this for a few days, but JQuery isn't working with my code in Dreamweaver. I contacted them and it's a coding issue. When I copy my code to JSFiddle it works, but doesn't work with my HTML. Here is the JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/mufeeza/36cmxwxc/

Here is how I link it in my HTML:

```
<script src="jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/home.js"></script>
```

Here is the JS File:

```
$('#contact').on('mouseenter', function () {
    "use strict";
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("https://image.ibb.co/fmOqzv/Contact.png")');
    $('.intro').css('opacity', '0');
});

$('#contact').on('mouseleave', function () {
    "use strict";

    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-white-solid-color-background.jpg)');
    $('.intro').css('opacity', '1');
});

$('#design').on('mouseenter', function () {
    "use strict";

    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("https://image.ibb.co/d2Dqzv/Portfolio.png")');
    $('.intro').css('opacity', '0');

});

$('#design').on('mouseleave', function () {
    "use strict";

    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-white-solid-color-background.jpg)');
    $('.intro').css('opacity', '1');
});

$('#develop').on('mouseenter', function () {
    "use strict";

    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("https://image.ibb.co/mSQPuv/develop.png")');
    $('.intro').css('opacity', '0');

});

$('#develop').on('mouseleave', function () {
    "use strict";
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-white-solid-color-background.jpg)');
    $('.intro').css('opacity', '1');
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you're loading you js file before loading the jQuery file, always load the jQuery file first.

Comment: Try replacing your jquery from CDN to see what happens: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> My other thoughts would be your path to the src is a miss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsFiddle wraps your JavaScript code in a window onload event handler by default (`window.onload=function(){...`). You can do that, wrap it in a [`$(document).ready(function() {` call](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), or move it to load at the end of the document, before the closing body element (`</body>`).

Comment: Moving it to the end of the HTML document worked! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery needs to look for the HTML nodes when executing.

If your your Jquery file is included in the `<head>` of HTML, Jquery needs to wait until all the HTML is fully loaded to find the HTML nodes, so you need to tell Jquery to execute after the DOM is loaded, either by wrapping your function in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //jQuery code here 
});
```

or

```
$(function(){ 
  //jQuery code here 
});
```

If Jquery is included at the bottom of the HTML before `</body>` tag, meaning that it will execute after the HTML is loaded, and no need to tell Jquery to wait.